# "could not import Crypto" running "conda install numpy"

Tags: python, anaconda, pycrypto

In the Linux subsystem for Windows10 I have encountered a new error when trying to conda install, update, remove any new package.

For example:

```
c/.../...$ conda install numpy
Error: could not import Crypto (required for signature verification).
    Run the following command:

    $ conda install -n root pycrypto
```

If I enter the suggested command it returns the same error.

If anyone can solve this issue without having to clean install Python this would be helpful.

Here is my version of Python and Anaconda:

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

Comment: There are two packages: 'pycrypto' and 'crypto'. The 'pycrypto' package has module `Crypto` and the `crypto` package has module `crypto`. I believe this causes problems with case insensitivity. Try uninstalling both and installing only the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try  this first :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential 
sudo pip install crypto
sudo apt-get update
```

And then run the conda install again.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your proposed method and this did not work either. I believe that there is a typo in your method: pip install crypto not sudo pip install crypto.

Comment: adding sudo in front of command means that you running this command as root user. So problem is not on sudo, what does the error message says? Again same thing?

Comment: Updated the answer, recheck it

Comment: I tried your update and everything works fine this time but I am still getting the same error message. The comment from Galen tells us that there could be an insensitivity between crypto and Crypto. I will try to uninstall one or both and see if this makes any difference.

Comment: @JustinBeland If this is the issue and the `crypto` package is installed, you will have to uninstall `crypto` and `pycrypto` (if still installed incorrectly) and then reinstall `pycrypto`. If `pycrypto` is installed while `crypto` is around, the `pycrypto`'s installation will end up in `crypto`'s `crypto` directory instead of the correct-case `Crypto`.

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around with all of your suggestions I finally gave in and uninstalled anaconda using the command:

```
rm -rf anaconda2
```

I then downloaded the appropriate installation file from the anaconda website then entered the following command into the terminal:

```
bash Anaconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

All straightforward stuff...
I will now take 30 minutes (or so) to re-install all of the packages. Thanks for all of your help guys as I very much appreciate the prompt responses.